# Create dynamic arguments for url_for in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a jinja2 template which I reuse for different Flask routes. All of these routes have a single required parameter and handle only `GET` requests, but some routes may have extra arguments.

Is there a way to append extra arguments onto `url_for()`?

---

Something like

```
url_for(my_custom_url, oid=oid, args=extra_args)
```

which will render to (depending on the route endpoint):

```
# route 'doit/<oid>' with arguments
doit/123?name=bob&age=45

# route 'other/<oid>' without arguments
other/123
```

My use case would be to provide links with predefined query arguments:

```
<a href=" {{ url_for('doit', oid=oid, args=extra_args }} ">A specific query</a>
<a href=" {{ url_for('other', oid=oid) }} ">A generic query</a>
```

I would like to run this template without JavaScript, so I would not like to assign a click listener and use AJAX to do a `GET` request for each link if that is possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any arguments that don't match route parameters will be added as the query string.  Assuming `extra_args` is a dict, just unpack it.

```
extra_args = {'hello': 'world'}
url_for('doit', oid=oid, **extra_args)
# /doit/123?hello=world
url_for('doit', oid=oid, hello='davidism')
# /doit/123?hello=davidism
```

Then access them in the view with `request.args`:

```
@app.route('/doit/<int:oid>')
def doit(oid)
    hello = request.args.get('hello')
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Using your example, this wound generate the URLs like you requested if you know your arguments in advance.

```
<a href=" {{ url_for('doit', oid=oid, name='bob', age=45 }} ">A specific query</a>

<a href=" {{ url_for('other', oid=oid) }} ">A generic query</a>
```

@davidism's answer would be preferred if your set of arguments isn't known until runtime and are stored in a dictionary.